# How to globally change the value of an if (so it can be changed in a tabular)

Tags: tables, conditionals

I'd like to toggle between two values each time a macro is called.  I can make it work, unless it's in a tabular.  I'd like to make it work in a tabular.  I assume this has something to do with scope.

```
\documentclass{article}

\newif\ifToggle\Togglefalse
\newcommand\checktoggle{
  \ifToggle \Togglefalse
    Toggle was true%
  \else \Toggletrue
    Toggle was false%
  \fi}

\begin{document}
This seems to work:\par
\checktoggle.\par
\checktoggle.\par
\checktoggle.\par

\bigskip
But not in tabular:

\begin{tabular}{ll}
  \checktoggle & 1 \\
  \checktoggle & 2
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

Comment: The assignment is not happening globally.  I'm not all that familiar with this construct, but you might try adding `\global\Togglefalse` and `\global\Toggletrue`.  If that doesn't work, then someone else will have to explain how to get the value assigned globally.

Comment: That's it, or at least it works in this toy example.  I'll try it for real tomorrow.  I figured I had a scope problem, but I didn't know how to change it globally.

Comment: Yes, this seems to work well.  @A.Ellett, if you make this an answer I can accept it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could put `\global` in front of every use, relying on the fact that the macros all work by pure expansion and so the `\global`  does finally apply to the correct assignment, but simpler and safer is to define the toggle to be a global switch (cf for example `\if@nobreak` in tthe latex format)

```
\documentclass{article}

%\newif\ifToggle
\def\Toggletrue{\global\let\ifToggle\iftrue}
\def\Togglefalse{\global\let\ifToggle\iffalse}
\Togglefalse
\newcommand\checktoggle{%
  \ifToggle \Togglefalse
    Toggle was true%
  \else \Toggletrue
    Toggle was false%
  \fi}

\begin{document}
This seems to work:\par
\checktoggle.\par
\checktoggle.\par
\checktoggle.\par

\bigskip
But not in tabular:

\begin{tabular}{ll}
  \checktoggle & 1 \\
  \checktoggle & 2
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

Comment: There is something I'm not understanding.  How is this safer?  You say I "could put `\global` in front of every use", but doesn't this also put `\global` in front of every use, just buried in one extra layer of macros?  What am I missing?

Comment: @dedded compare with  `\global\setlength\textwidth{3pt}`  that seems to work but fails if you load `calc` package as it only works if `\setlength` only does expansion and so `\global` applies to the underlying register assignment not (as happens with `calc` some `\def\@tempa{...}` internal assignment.) So it is "safer" in the sense that you know which assignment `\global` applies to. It is unlikely anyone redefines `\newif`-defined commands but...  given how often people try things like `\global\newcommand` it seems worth stressing that in general you can not prefix things with `\global`

Comment: OK, that makes sense.

Comment: @dedded also the `\global` is one level of expansion down but it's not an "extra" level of expansion as those definitions (without `\global`) are the definitions that `\newif` makes)